# How remove empty element from string array in one line?

Tags: linq, arrays, split

```
string[] ssss = "1,2,,3".Split(new[] {','})
                  .Where(a=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
                  .Select();
```

How does this works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also use

```
"1,2,,3".Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] ssss = "1,2,,3".Split(new [] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] ssss = "1,2,,3".Split(new[] {','}).Where(a=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)).ToArray();
```

Comment: This option is the better choice for .NET Compact Framework as it doesn't accept the same Split signature as .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ssss = "1,2,,3".Split(new[] {','}).Where(a=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a));
foreach (string s in ssss)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```